# How can I create a column in my data frame, in Python using if and or statements?

Tags: python, pandas, if-statement

[image]

I am looking to create a column called "Assign Number 1 or 2" with the following logic:

If Posting Archived At (GMT) is between "January 22" and "June 22" and Profile Archive Reason is "Offer Declined*" or "Withdrawn" then assign 1

AND

If Posting Archived At (GMT) is between "July 22" and "December 22" and Profile Archive Reason is "Offer Declined* " or "Withdrawn" then assign 2?

I started with the below:

```
df['Assign Number 1 or 2'] = ['1' if i = 'Offer Declined* ' or i = 'Withdrawn' else '0' for i in df['Profile Archive Reason']]
```

Comment: can you show the code which you have tried?

Comment: Done! Included what I started with

Answer (score 0):

use a function with apply and lambda:

```
import pandas as pd

def my_func(row):
    if row.bname == "textbook":
        return "something"
    if row.bname == "b":
        return "something_else"

    return "not_found"

books = [{"bname": "textbook", "weight": 500, "price": 800},
   {"bname": "notebook", "weight": 100, "price": 200},
   {"bname": "storybook", "weight": 700, "price": 1000},
   {"bname": "whatever", "weight": 500, "price": 1200}]

df = pd.DataFrame(books)

df["new_colums"] = df.apply(lambda x: my_func(x),axis=1)
print(df)
```

returns

```
       bname  weight  price new_colums
0   textbook     500    800  something
1   notebook     100    200  not_found
2  storybook     700   1000  not_found
3   whatever     500   1200  not_found
```

Comment: Just to double check, is "row" the row header, within my_func(row)?

Comment: Apply senda the complete row to the function. In the function it is called "row"